# net::Error Connection Refused

Tags: javascript, gruntjs

it didn't throw error with localhost but when our product is hosted on server then it throws error and not able to find the solution

Snippet from Chrome JavaScript console

> hosted_Server:35729/livereload.js?snipver=1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Code:

```
var LIVERELOAD_PORT = 35729,
lrSnippet = require('connect-livereload')({
   port: LIVERELOAD_PORT
}),
mountFolder = function( connect, dir ) {
   return connect.static(require('path').resolve(dir));
};
```

Comment: Can you add some code?

Comment: var
  LIVERELOAD_PORT = 35729,
  lrSnippet = require('connect-livereload')({ port: LIVERELOAD_PORT }),
  mountFolder = function( connect, dir ) {
    return connect.static(require('path').resolve(dir));
  };